# UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username while creating the user using a custom designed form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django and I am working on student login for examination portal.  I am basically passing two forms in my view. One form is for getting the user details and second is for storing details of student.
I have used django widget tweak package to load the fields of my forms. My user gets created but at the same time I still get the error- UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username.

Here's my model.py

```
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput()
        }

class StudentInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = StudentInfo
        fields = ['mobile','branch']
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    userForm= forms.StudentForm()
    studentForm=forms.StudentInfoForm()
    mydict={'userForm':userForm,'studentForm':studentForm}
    if request.method=='POST':
        userForm=forms.StudentForm(request.POST)
        studentForm=forms.StudentInfoForm(request.POST)
        if userForm.is_valid() and studentForm.is_valid():
            user=userForm.save()
            user.is_active = True
            user.set_password(user.password)
            messages.success(request,"Student User created Succesfully.")

            student=studentForm.save(commit=False)
            student.user=user
            student.save()
            
            my_student_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='STUDENT')
            my_student_group[0].user_set.add(user)
            return redirect('login')
        
    return render(request,'student_signup.html',context=mydict)
```

html file

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Student Signup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;">Student Signup</h1>
    <div class="container mt-5" style="width: 50%;">

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
          {
          {% render_field userForm.username type="text" class="form-control" %}

          
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
          
          {% render_field userForm.password type="password" class="form-control" %}

        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
            
            {% render_field userForm.email type="email" class="form-control" %}
  
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="branch" class="form-label">Branch</label>
            
            {% render_field studentForm.branch type="text" class="form-control" %}
  
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="mobile" class="form-label">Mobile</label>
             
            {% render_field studentForm.mobile type="number" class="form-control" %}
  
        </div>


        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

I searched on the internet and found that this happens when we save the form twice but I don't think I am doing so.I am calling the save method only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this occurs because your user instance is bound to the form and not a model instance itself which you then assign to your student instance

Try it like so:

```
def register(request):
    userForm= forms.StudentForm()
    studentForm=forms.StudentInfoForm()
    mydict={'userForm':userForm,'studentForm':studentForm}
    if request.method=='POST':
        userForm=forms.StudentForm(request.POST)
        studentForm=forms.StudentInfoForm(request.POST)
        if userForm.is_valid() and studentForm.is_valid():
            user=userForm.save()
            user.is_active = True
            user.set_password(user.password)
            messages.success(request,"Student User created Succesfully.")

            student=studentForm.save(commit=False)
            student.user=user.instance  # user is bound to the form instance not the model instance
            student.save()
            
            my_student_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='STUDENT')
            my_student_group[0].user_set.add(user)
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request,'student_signup.html',context=mydict)
```

Comment: That error got solved I am getting new error NOT NULL constraint failed: student_studentinfo.mobile

Comment: @JatinArora set `null=True` on your mobile field :)

Comment: Thanks for helping although actually, i was doing a small mistake, I was assigning the same form to studentForm=forms.StudentForm(request.POST). Which is a mistake. actually, it should be studentForm=forms.StudentInfoForm(request.POST). I have made the changes to the code, so now there is no mistake in the code mentioned in the question.